# How to carry snackbar over to next page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a form and I want to redirect to the home page upon submission.  I also want a snackbar to appear upon submission, however, the snackbar will only appear on my form page.  When it gets redirected, the snackbar disappears.  Is there a way I can have the snackbar remain onscreen even after it redirects?

```
export default function Form() {
    const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm();
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const history = useHistory();
    const handleClose = () => {
      setOpen(false);
    }
    const redir = (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        history.push('/')
        setOpen(true);
        console.log(open);
        }  
   return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(redir)}>
                <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleClose}>
                    <Alert severity='success' onClose={handleClose}>
                        Success! Your message has been sent.
                    </Alert>
                </Snackbar>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should call **Snackbar** component with [open, setOpen] not in the Form, but in the Parent component and pass **setOpen** to the Form and call it in redir function.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the router, you can pass the props with push.

```
history.push({
  pathname: '/',
  openSnackbar: true
});
```

And then in your parent component you have a state for it

```
const [snackbar, setSnackbar] = useState(location.openSnackbar);
```

You might need to add a ternary in the useState just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd use implement the snackbar using HOC or context to make it easier to use anywhere.

Now the solution that works for me: I use it when the user logs in and navigates into the home page.

In the login handler, I did something like this:

```
if (login === true) {
  localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", "true")
//the rest of your implementation
}
```

In the home page, I did:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn");
    if (isLoggedIn === "true") {
      // Show Snackbar
      snackbar("Welcome user!");

      // Reset the flag in localStorage
      localStorage.removeItem("isLoggedIn");
    }
  }, []);
```